# Memory limit exceeded in Python

Tags: python, memory, python-3.5

I am solving a problem that needs either a list of integers or a dictionary of size 10^18. Upon running the code the compiler throws an error message saying "Memory Limit Exceeded".

Here is my code:

```
def fun(l, r, p):
    #f = [None, 1, 1]
    f = {0:0, 1:1, 2:1}
    su = 0
    for i in range(1, r):
        if i%2 == 0:
            f[i+2] = 2*f[i+1] - f[i] + 2
            #f.append(2*f[i+1] - f[i] + 2)
        else:
            f[i+2] = 3*f[i]
            #f.append(3*f[i])

    for k in range(l, r):
        su = su + f[k]

    su = (su + f[r]) % p
    print(su)

t, p = input().split()
p = int(p)
t = int(t)
#t = 3
#p = 100000007
for i in range(t):
    l , r = input().split()
    l = int(l)
    r = int(r)
    fun(l, r, p)
```

It is showing memory limit exceeded with a maximum memory usage of 306612 KiB.

Comment: Do you really have a computer with 1 exabytes of memory? Because if you have that you must be a time traveler from the distant future and I want to borrow your time machine.

Comment: you got to device an algorithm which runs in finite amount of memory space. you cannot expect to get infinite amount of memory... at least in this time.... 10^18?

Answer (score 1):

Two observations here:

- You don't need to store all numbers simultaneously. You can use the deque and generator functions to generate the numbers by keeping track of only the last three digits generated instead of the entire sequence.

  ```
    import itertools
    from collections import deque

    def infinite_fun_generator():
        seed = [0, 1, 1]
        dq = deque(maxlen=2)
        dq.extend(seed)
        yield from seed
        for i in itertools.count(1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                dq.append(2 * dq[-1] - dq[-2] + 2)
            else:
                dq.append(3 * dq[-2])
            yield dq[-1]

    def fun(l, r, p):
        funs = itertools.islice(infinite_fun_generator(), l, r + 1)
        summed_funs = itertools.accumulate(funs, lambda a, b: (a + b) % p)
        return deque(summed_funs, maxlen=1)[-1]
  ```
- You might have a better chance asking this in Math.SE since I don't want to do the math right now, but just like with the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) there's likely an analytic solution that you can use to compute the nth member of the sequence analytically without having to iteratively compute the intermediate numbers and it may even be possible to analytically derive a formula to compute the sums in constant time.

Comment: This can perfectly remove memory error but this is not able to remove Time Limit Exceeded error as each test case of the range  10^18 is gonna take nearly 5sec to get executed which is not a good solution .